How are B-spline basis properly defined with boundary knots repetition?
I am having trouble understanding how to calculate the B-spline basis function of order $p+1$ when the first and last knots have multiplicity $p+1$ due to the division by zero problem.
Fact 1  The recursive formula of B-spline basis (Wikipedia):

Fact 2 For B-spline of order $p+1$ and distinct knots $s_1, \dots, s_n$, it is a common practice to add $p$ extra $s_1$ and $s_n$ to the knots to account for the boundary approximation. The actual knots are
$$ t_1, \dots, t_{n+2p}, $$
where
$$\begin{aligned}
&t_1, \dots, t_{p+1} = s_1, \\
&t_{n+p-1}, \dots, t_{n+2p} = s_n, \\
&t_{p+i} = s_{i},\ 1\leq i\leq n.
\end{aligned}$$
Question In the recursive formula, the devision by zero problem will occur when $i=1$ or $i=n+p-1$. How can we properly define B-spline in this case? In addition, I am wondering how to rigorously write the program calculating B-spline basis with these knots padding.

In the recursion you multiply lower degree basis functions by linear functions taking values between $0$ and $1$ over the interval of support of the basis function they are multiplied with.
When the denominator is $0$, the linear function is squeezed to an infinitely steep line between $0$ and $1$. You can replace the zero division fractions by any numbers (like just $0$ to reduce the number of operations), if you don't care how the spline is evaluated in points of discontinuity. Evaluating continuous points of the spline won't be affected by the choice.
If you want the spline to be right or left continuous, you have to replace zero division fractions by $0$ or $1$ depending on the sign of the parameter in the numerator, and adjust $B_{i,0}$ to also be left or right continuous.
Another choice is to replace them by $0.5$ and changing $B_{i,0}$ to equal $0.5$ at the $t_i$ and $t_{i+1}$. This way any spline will be everywhere equal to the average of the limits from left and right. You need this if you wanna use the recursive formulas for inner products of basis functions from On Calculating with B-Splines II. Integration that uses evaluation of possibly discontinuous points of basis functions.
